# How to Prevent Spotlight from Indexing Non-Apps in /Applications Directory?

Tags: macos, spotlight, alfred

The only thing I need indexed in the /Applications folder are the .app files.

Is there any way to setup a filter to have mds or Spotlight ignore everything in /Applications except .apps?

Otherwise, would it be possible to setup a rule for Alfred to omit any non-.app records from /Applications?  I still want documents indexed and returned, just not from that specific directory.

OS X 10.6.8 if you're wondering.

Comment: Why do you have non-apps in `/Applications`?

Comment: Many apps choose to store files in /Applications.  For instance Microsoft Office comes with an "Office" folder with a variety of non .app files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Applications features](http://support.alfredapp.com/features:applications):

> Spotlight Comments can also be used to ignore apps: Add "alfred:ignore" to the Spotlight Comment and Alfred will ignore the application or file.

[image]

So, you could at least tell it to ignore a set of documents you know before. However, I don't think going the other way round is possible at the moment (i.e. setting up a rule like "Don't index non-.app files").

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong there, can't try everything out.

Comment: you may want to pear down your suggestions to one, the only real option i see is having a script tag all non-.app files in /Applications with alfred:ignore

Comment: Well, as far as I understand it, Alfred does not index what Spotlight can't index, so here you have a few ways to achieve that.

Comment: Modifiying the spotlight settings files does not achieve this, moving the files and symlinking them is outside the constraints of the question, and the .noindex idea simply does not apply.  If you cut out the incorrect info and condense it into one concise and correct answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done so. Sorry, was just trying to offer a few ideas that go beyond your use case.